# Sharing C functions between two XS Perl modues

Tags: c, perl, libraries, xs

I have a Perl module `A` that is a XS based module. I have an `A.xs` file, and an `aux_A.c` file, where I have some standard C functions. I use `DynaLoader`, and it works file.

Now, I have a new module `B`, that is also a XS module. I also have the `B.xs` file, and the `aux_B.c` file. Now, I want that a standard C function defined in `aux_B.c` file to be able to use a function defined in `aux_A.c` file.

One option is to make A module to create a standard C library, and link B module with it. But I was trying to get away from that option.

Is there any other way to go?

What I am currently getting is DynaLoader complaining on undefined symbol when trying to load the `B.so` library.

Thanks
Alberto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make module A export its C symbols with `DynaLoader`, you have to add the following to `A.pm`:

```
sub dl_load_flags { 1 }
```

This is badly documented, unfortunately. See [this thread on PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691130) and the [`DynaLoader`source code](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.0/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader_pm.PL#L102) for more details. The effect of the flag is to set `RTLD_GLOBAL` when loading `A.so` with [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) which makes its symbols available to other shared objects.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed this entry in the DynaLoader doc, but it wasn't clear. Thank you!